# How can I get traces of Nservicebus using Jaeger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nservicebus, jaeger

I have gone through Jaeger Documentation. They have specified that how will Jaeger will work the HTTP request kind of scenario but if I want to get traces of Nservicebus's to publish/subscribe method then How will I get using Jaeger?

Is it possible? Or Jaeger only works with HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, you have to plug a behaviour into NSB that uses open telemetry
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet
You will have to write custom code.
Plus you can do push metrics as well as shown in our app insights, Prometheus and other samples.

Let's continue the conversation in our support channels?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for a solution for this. You should be able to do this currently using the `NServiceBus.Extensions.Diagnostics.OpenTelemetry` package from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Extensions.Diagnostics.OpenTelemetry). This is built by Jimmy Bogard and instruments NServiceBus with the required support for `Open Telemetry`.

The source for this is available [here](https://github.com/jbogard/NServiceBus.Extensions.Diagnostics.OpenTelemetry). You can connect this to any backend of your choice that supports `Open Telemetry` including but not limited to `Jaeger` and `Zipkin`.

Additionally, here is an [example](https://github.com/jbogard/nsb-diagnostics-poc) that shows this in action.